# Unable to click child element as parent is always in focus

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a list of buttons, and on hover, a small (x) appears in the top right corner of the button. I am trying to attach a click handler on the (x), however, when ever i click it, the actually button is clicked, rather than the (x).

Code:

```
btnArray.forEach(function (button) {

    const btn = document.createElement('div');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = button.name;
    btn.onClick = evt => {
        // do soemthing on click
    }

    btn.onmouseover = function(e) {
        var me = d3.select(btn);
        me.append('div')
            .classed({'btn-close': true})
            .append('div')
            .classed({'btn-x-icon': true})
            .text('x')
            .on('click', function() {
                alert('you clicked on the x!');
            });
    }

    btn.onmouseout = function(e) {
        var me = d3.select(btn);
        me.selectAll('.btn-close')
            .remove();
    }

    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(button.name))

});
```

Even when i place my mouse over the (x), the parent button still appears to be in focus.

---

UPDATE

I can click on the icon by increasing the z-index of the (x) icon.

Howvever, when clicking, the (x) onclick is called as well as the main btn.onclick call.

---

UPDATE

Markup:

```
<button type="button" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-primary">
    Check out

    <div class="btn-close">
        <div class="btn-x-icon">x</div>
    </div>

</button>
```

Comment: Now that your z-index is fixed, you need to inspect the `event.target` to ensure you only execute your code if the `X` was the target. You could stop propagation but that is a double edged sword as when you need to propagate you now can't anymore. Hence I would recommend to check the [**event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) instead

Comment: @Fran - added markup

Answer (score 1):

Using [**event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) you can ensure you only respond to the correct element being clicked.

> In the below examples I only added identifiers so I can attach the
>   click events easier for demonstration but the code inside the event
>   handlers is applicable as is to your code off course.
>
> Also, note that I did not specify a `event` parameter in the handler
>   because `event` is assigned automatically, when specifying a parameter
>   for the event such as `'click', function(evt)` you are now using the
>   event object as specified by d3 which may or may not be the same event
>   object.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (event.target == this) {
    console.log('button clicked')
  }
})

var button = document.getElementById("close");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('close clicked')
})
```

```css
#close {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-primary">
    Check out
    <div id="close" class="btn-close">
        <div class="btn-x-icon">x</div>
    </div>

</button>
```

Alternatively you can use [**stopPropagation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('button clicked')
})

var button = document.getElementById("close");
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('close clicked')
})
```

```css
#close {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" type="button" value="Checkout" class="btn btn-primary">
    Check out
    <div id="close" class="btn-close">
        <div class="btn-x-icon">x</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the propagation event on click. The event, once is produced, is propagated to all the inherent elements. You should stop that propagation in order to avoid execute more handlers for that event.

More about that Event bubbling (in the other way) and propagation
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventbubbling.htm
https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/

```
btnArray.forEach(function (button) {

    const btn = document.createElement('div');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = button.name;
    btn.onClick = evt => {
        // do soemthing on click
    }

    btn.onmouseover = function(e) {
        var me = d3.select(btn);
        me.append('div')
            .classed({'btn-close': true})
            .text('x')
            .on('click', function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                alert('you clicked on the x!');
            });
    }

    btn.onmouseout = function(e) {
        var me = d3.select(btn);
        me.selectAll('.btn-close')
            .remove();
    }

    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(button.name))

});
```

Comment: thanks for the info.Have made changes, but doesnt seem to improve.

Comment: Then I can only suggest to create the _'x'_  div outside the _onmouseover_ method with the binded function on _click_ and show and hide it on mousehover (the css pseudo class :hover should be enough).